# C pointer cast - value truncation

Tags: c, pointers

### The Question

Here's the code that casts a pointer to 16-bit value into a pointer to 32-bit value:

```
int low_level_read(uint32_t * read_data)
{
   // some low level access to get 32-bit read here
}

int i2c_read(uint16_t * data)
{
   low_level_read((uint32_t *) data);

   printf("data=0x%X\n", *data);
}
```

Expected:

- low_level_read obtains: 0x0000C101
- i2c_read obtains:       0xC101

Observed:

- low_level_read obtains: 0x0000C101
- i2c_read obtains:       0x0000

**Why does it seem like it's truncating/cutting-off the *least significant* 16 bits?**

### My Solution to this problem

If the i2c_read() is modified to look like below, then this works as expected:

```
int i2c_read(uint16_t * data)
{
   uint32_t raw_data;
   low_level_read(raw_data);

   *data = (uint16_t) raw_data;
}
```

That's fine but I would still like to understand why the first piece of code is acting like that.

### My Educated Guess as to Why

When we pass in the pointer to i2c_read(), it was meant for 8-bits:

```
pointer address 0x100 ->
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

However when cast to (uint32_t *), it "grows" the size of what the memory location could hold to 32-bits:

```
pointer address 0x100 ->
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 ....  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

The 32-bit value is put into that location.
But when it truncates it, it actually truncates bits [15:0] and leaves the pointer address as 0x100. This means when it returns, I end up seeing what was bits [31:16] thus all zeros.

That's my best guess.

**Can someone explain this?** Thanks :).

Comment: Violation of effective type rule -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: When you call `printf()`, `*data` is a 16-bit quantity; that is what's passed to `printf()`.  If you want to pass a 32-bit quantity, you'll need a pointer to a 32-bit quantity, but `*data` is, and always will be, a 16-bit quantity.

Comment: Look up "endianness".

Comment: Change the print to `printf("data=0x%X\n", (unsigned int)*data);`, let us know if this changes the output

Comment: Alignment violation is a third possible problem here. It would improve the question to show the calling code (specifically, how the argument is obtained)

Comment: Olaf: could you provide a reference for "Violation of effective type rule"?

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: Thanks, but I was more looking for an answer that explains the mechanism of why this happens. Something like why the memory management or how C interprets the code.

Comment: Peter: I believe endianness is not relevant to this question. The endianness between low_level_read() and i2c_read() does not change. The only thing that is happening is that I'm casting the pointer type from (uint16_t *) to (uint32_t *). Unless the endianness effects how the truncation of pointer casts occurs, I don't see how endianness is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i2c_read()` is receiving argument `uint16_t *data` which says "here is an address to 2 bytes of memory":

`data --> [ByteA][ByteB]`

When you perform the cast `(uint32_t*)data`, you're now claiming that `data` is an address to 4 bytes of memory:

`data --> [ByteA][ByteB][ByteC][ByteD]`

In good faith, low_level_read() uses the address that you passed as `uint32_t*` and populates all 4 bytes of memory as `[00][00][C1][01]`.  **This is bad.**  Pointer `data` has no rights to `[ByteC][ByteD]` and now you've overwritten memory that may have held some important data for some other part of your program.

Back in `i2c_read()` at the `printf()`, variable `data` goes back to being just a `uint16_t*` and `*data` reads just `[ByteA][ByteB]` as the value to print (`[00][00]`).
If you instead called `printf("℅08X", *(uint32_t*)data)`, 4 bytes would be read and `0x00000C01` would print.

To fix your code, ensure that the argument types of `i2c_read()` and `low_level_read()` are the same.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the reason that I thought as well. Would you have a reference for this?

Comment: uhh..."The Type's The Thing" section of this link seems to address this topic - (https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)[https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html].  Note that it has a typo - sizeof(short) --> 2